# How can I prevent pasting after org-copy-visible leaving cursor at end of text?

Tags: org-mode, evil, copy-paste

In evil-mode, if I use `3yy` to copy three lines, then move somewhere else in my file and do `P` (`evil-paste-before`), the three lines are pasted before the line with the cursor, and the cursor is left at the top of the pasted text.

If however I copy a section of text using `org-copy-visible` and paste that using `P`, the cursor ends up at the bottom of the pasted text.

I can get the desired result (cursor left at start of text) in the latter case if I subsequently do an undo / redo but that is too hacky even for me.

How can I paste following a call to `org-copy-visible` and leave the cursor at the start of the pasted text?

Comment: Try `C-x C-x` (which runs the function `exchange-point-and-mark`) or its evil equivalent, after the paste.

Comment: `C-x C-x` will activate the region incidentally, you can use `C-u C-SPC` to pop the mark. Or instead, use emacs' built-in `C-y` (yank), when adding `C-u`, it paste text after point. dunno whether evil provides this functionality or not.

Comment: Sorry, just found you can C-u C-x C-x to not activate the region.

Comment: @nichijou: feel free to make your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the vim manual, just `p` would do, but unluckily when I tried in Vim, both leave cursor after the new text, and evil didn't bind `gp` at all. dead end for me.

```
                                                        p put E353
["x]p                   Put the text [from register x] after the cursor
                        [count] times.

...

                                                        gp
["x]gp                  Just like "p", but leave the cursor just after the new
                        text.
```

The Emacs way:

> The basic yanking command is C-y (yank).  It inserts the most recent kill, leaving the cursor at the end of the inserted text.  It also sets the mark at the beginning of the inserted text, without activating the mark; this lets you jump easily to that position, if you wish, with C-u C-<SPC>
>
> With a plain prefix argument (C-u C-y), the command instead leaves the cursor in front of the inserted text, and sets the mark at the end. Using any other prefix argument specifies an earlier kill; e.g., C-u 4 C-y reinserts the fourth most recent kill.

Good news is evil's paste commands set mark of the other side of newly pasted text for you too. You can go to the other side either:

- C-x C-x (exchange-point-and-mark) ::  if transient-mark-mode is on, add C-u to avoid activating the region incidently.
- C-u C-<SPC>